# Higher Order Lagrange

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

This is a very generic question, but in general, will having a higher order Lagrange polynomial give you a better estimation for a function (at a specific point $z$) than a smaller order Lagrange? I was working with an example and I found this to be false, but I just wanted to see if this is true and maybe I am doing something wrong in my calculations.

Comment: No, fitting a high degree polynomial to data often yields worse out-of-sample predictions. If you plot the high degree polynomial you can see it might do wild things in between your data points.

Comment: @littleO Ah ok. My reasoning was that the more data points we use, the smaller the error. Why isn't this true?

Comment: See [Runge's phenomenon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon).